# Debugging Windows Store application on local machine

Tags: c#, debugging, windows-8, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am trying to debug Windows 8 C# Store application with Local Machine debugger. So, I added some incorrect line to `MainPage` constructor, after `InitializeComponent` call. I tried the code that causes `DivideByZero` or `NullReferenceException` - with the same results.

So, I execute "Start Debugging", and debugger breaks here:

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
        UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
        {
            if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
        };
#endif
```

Stack information is not available, it is impossible to detect where is an error (only first-chance exception message in the Output window gives a hint).

I tried to define `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` in the project preprocessor symbols. This time I got the following strange message: "**A debugger is attached to YourProgram.exe but not configured to debug this unhandled exception**".

Only when specific exception type is checked in the "Exceptions" dialog, and `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` is defined, I managed to break on the line which caused the error.

So, what is the right way to break on the offending line, like is was in traditional desktop applications debugging? If possible, without modifying Exceptions list. And what is exactly the purpose of `DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION` constant?

Comment: Put `System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();` just before the exception is thrown. That will launch the debugger so you can step through and see where the problem is.

Comment: @Jack Hughes - it changes something in the debugger behavior, but I am trying to learn, how to debug an error in unknown place. It is impossible to add `Debugger.Launch` before every line in the program...

Answer (score 21):

It looks like a xaml parsing exception. Have you be able to look at the exception message and see where the error is?

Here is some sample screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Missed this. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

Well when you start Visual Studio you must click on debug and then  Options and Settings and then General in Debugging and click on Enable Just My Code.

Comment: This is the absolutely rightest anwser and should be accepted accordingly.

Comment: This did not solve my issue, I had `Enable Just My Code` checked but no help.

Answer (score 3):

It can be helpful to enable "Common Language Runtime Exceptions" in "Debug/Windows/Exception Settings" before debugging.
Visual studio will now break on the actual error.

[image]